# Freemarker: Get element from array by index

Tags: freemarker

I have this code:

```
<#local slots = time_utils.get_slots(objectArray) />
<#local days = time_utils.get_short_days(objectArray) />
<#local index = 0 />
<#list days as day>
    <#list slots as slot>
        <#if time_utils.is_slot_available(objectArray[index], slot, day)> bla bla </#if>
        <#local index = index + 1 />
    </#list>
</#list>
```

The function:

```
<#function is_slot_available date slot short_date>
    <#local hour_of_date = '${date.startsAt?string["HH"]}' />    
    <#local day_of_date = '${date.startsAt?string["dd"]}' /> 
    <#if (hour_of_date == '${slot[6..7]}') && (day_of_date == '${short_date[short_date?length-5..short_date?length-4]}')>
        <#return true />    
    </#if>
    <#return false />
</#function>
```

When I run this code, I have the error:
**Error executing macro: is_slot_available
required parameter: date is not specified.**
I don't get this error when I replace `index` by 0 or any number in `objectArray[index]` in the function call.
So what's the rignt way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed that when you call the function, you pass `day` as `slot` and `slot` as `short_date`?

Comment: No I didn't. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the value of `index` increases until it goes out of range, or runs into an array item that stores `null`. (Unrelated to your problem, but note that this is possible: `<#local index++ />`)

Comment: You were right. The problem is that my index goes out of range. Thanks pal!! But I can't use `++`, it says: `Encountered "+", but was expecting one of: "=", "in", ">"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ddekany:

> I guess the value of index increases until it goes out of range, or
>   runs into an array item that stores null.

That was the problem.